# Initializing opengl non-graphical application

Tags: opengl

I am writing a non-graphical command-line tool which calls some OpenGL functions.

```
const int DEFAULT_VERSION_MAJOR = 4;
const int DEFAULT_VERSION_MINOR = 3;

const auto DEFAULT_PROFILE = QGLFormat::CoreProfile;

void main ()
{
    QGLFormat format;
    {
        format.setVersion (
            DEFAULT_VERSION_MAJOR,
            DEFAULT_VERSION_MINOR);

        format.setProfile (DEFAULT_PROFILE);
    }

    QGLContext context (format);

    // EDIT: this line is failing.
    if (false == context.isValid ())
    {
        std::cerr << "No valid OpenGL context created." << std::endl;

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    context.makeCurrent ();

    if (const GLenum err = glewInit (); GLEW_OK != err)
    {
        std::cerr
            << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
            << ": glewInit() returned "
            << glewGetErrorString (err)
            << std::endl;
    }
    
    glEnable (GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT);

    // SEGMENTATION FAULT        
    glDebugMessageCallback ((GLDEBUGPROC) message_callback, nullptr);
```

I assume this is segfaulting because the libraries are not properly initialized (function pointers not set up or whatever).

The GLEW error is `Missing GL version`.

This tool will need to create OpenGL objects e.g. compile shaders, but not draw anything.

What are the minimum steps to get OpenGL libraries working for a non-graphical application?

(A cross-platform solution would be nice, a Linux-only solution will be fine.)

Comment: Can you check the return value from `glewInit`?  Are you sure the context created/set by `create_context_and_make_current` is valid?

Comment: Edited. The context is invalid. What now?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to call `QGLContext::create`. That (probably) answers this question, and I'll post another question directed at the QGLContext problem.